# iOS Web app - show content only if added to home screen?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

I've previously seen a 'solution' to this, but with a major flaw!

Here's what I'm trying to achieve;

I have a web-app that requires a user to login before it can be used. For a variety of reasons, I don't want it to be used in regular Safari, only via the Home Screen (aesthetically, it only really 'works' when in full screen).

So, when a user browses to the site, it should detect whether it's been opened via the home screen (in which case it shows the login page) or regular safari (in which case it shows a splash screen inviting the viewer to add it to their home screen).

I can successfully detect whether it's opened via the Home Screen or now (using window.navigator.standalone), however all the solutions I've come across involve redirecting the user to a different page if it's not opened via the home screen.  The problem with this is that the user would be bookmarking (or adding to home screen) the wrong page.  As far as I'm aware, there's no way to specify a different page to be added to the home screen.

I've tried the following, which doesn't seem to work;

```
/* Added to login page head */
$(document).ready()
        if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
            if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
                initialize();
            }else{
                $('.container').load('/install.cfm')
            }
        }else{
            $('.container').load('/install.cfm')
        }
```

Edit : Based on @scunliffe's comment, I have now tried the following, which also doesn't work (jQuery is loaded before the script executes, so that shouldn't be the problem);

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
            if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
                $('#logindiv').show;
            }else{
                $('#installdiv').show;
            }
        }else{
            $('#installdiv').show;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you alter your logic so that the login page is the default but if the user is on an iphone/iOS device? then they get a message if **not** running standalone?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1){//test for other iOS devices?
        if(window.navigator.standalone == true){
            //do stuff!
            initialize();
        } else {
            //show message telling user to add to their home screen...
        }
    } else {
        //show message that this must be run on device X/Y/Z...
    }
});
```

**Update:**

Based on your updated sample, you just need to modify the code to call show/hide as a method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1){
    if(window.navigator.standalone == true){
      $('#logindiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#installdiv').show();
    }
  } else {
    $('#installdiv').show();
  }
});
```

and

```
<div id="logindiv">
  ...stuff to login here...
</div>
<div id="installdiv">
  ...note to install here...
</div>
```

Comment: The login page *is* the default (purely because it shows up if the user isn't logged in - by preventing it being used in Safari, the user should only be able to login by accessing it through the home screen).  My problem is getting the page display appropriate - i.e I want to show different content when the user is viewing in regular safari, and only the login page when via the home screen. I thought I'd be able to use a combination of the above code, with jQuery .load to achieve this, but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Just to clarify I'm suggesting you only have 1 physical page... it shows the login stuff when applicable... but shows notifications if either not launched from the home screen, or not on an iOS device. (but it is all the same physical page)

Comment: Ahhhh, I hadn't thought of doing it that way! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: ok, so I've tried it this way (forgive my poor JS - still finding my feet!).  Setup 2 divs with display:none, one with the login form, the other a 'splash' prompting the user to add to home screen. The detection script is *supposed* to show the relevant div, but doesn't.

    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
                if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
                    $('#logindiv').show;
                }else{
                    $('#installdiv').show;
                }
            }else{
                $('#installdiv').show;
            }

Comment: Code didn't paste in well there, so have added it to my original question.

Comment: @Lee I updated my answer to reflect your update... I think you were just missing the `()` on the method calls ;-)

Comment: thanks, sadly I'm still getting an empty display (trying this both through safari & via home screen - as well as firefox, purely to see if firebug throws back anything).

Comment: a few paranoia checks. 1.) are you sure you have DIV's on your page with id attributes that match your *exact* values? e.g. `<div id="installdiv">` and `<div id="logindiv">`? 2.) are you sure you are calling this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready({.....});` call so that it *only* executes after that DOM content has loaded? (I'm tidying my sample to match)

Comment: thanks! I was missing the $(document).ready ... newbie error! Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `hash-trick` used in "Add to Home Screen" here is the example [here](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen/blob/master/examples/hash-trick/index.html)

Basically it checks to see if there is a hash at the end of the URL, if it does then that means it was added to the home screen if it doesn't then it can run a script then add the hash to the url. So when they add the link to the home screen and the next time they open the web app it would have the hash on the screen. Its kind of a messy way of doing it but it works.

Comment: Probably the only available option? Thanks for sharing. :)